# Github Desktop not detecting db.sqlite

Tags: github, commit, github-desktop

I'm currently deploying a Django project to Github using Github Desktop.

All changes are successfully detected and commited, except for db.sqlite3

When I copy that file to "Documents/Github/my-repository", there is no change and I can't commit.

[image]

[image]

I tried to pull but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the file `.gitignore` to see if that file is not black-listed. The `.gitignore` file is used to prevent files and directories from being committed. Read more [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).